# Small sample size - repeated measure ANOVA or something more simple?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, sample-size, diversity

I have data from an ecological study on wasp abundance and diversity across a forest which I am trying to analyse appropriately.

We have abundance data from ten locations that were sampled twice, three months apart.

These ten sites can then be split by their vegetation,into two vegetation types:

- Four sites = conifers dominant.
- Six sites = angiosperms dominant.

I am trying to assess differences in wasp abundance between sampling periods and vegetation type. In particular, the between vegetation type analysis is most interesting to me but I do not want to have to pool the data from each sampling period whilst at the same accounting for temporal pseudo-replication.

I thought a repeated-measure ANOVA or mixed model may be appropriate given the nature of these data.

TIME is a within-subject factor and VEG TYPE is a between subjects factor.

However, as my sample size is small (n=10 per sampling period and n=4 and n=6 for each vegetation type), I am unsure whether to proceed down this way or look for a less complex analysis.

So far, I have applied a repeated measure ANOVA...

To help clarify the model I have created:

1. ABUNDANCE = wasp abundance at each location - this was a count of
   number of wasps trapped.
2. TIME = I have treated this as the repeated measure factor, we trapped the wasps at same location twice, three
   months apart.
3. VEG = The vegetation community at each trapping location, either 1 = angiosperm type or 2 = conifer type
4. SITE = Site identifier for each trap location 1:10.

I used the following code:

```
WASP.AOV=aov(log(1+ABUNDANCE) ~ TIME+VEG+Error(SITE/TIME),data=WASP.ABUN)

summary(WASP.AOV)

Error: SITE
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
VEG        1  4.676   4.676   6.379 0.0355 *
Residuals  8  5.864   0.733                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: SITE:TIME
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
TIME       1 0.7423  0.7423   7.237 0.0248 *
Residuals  9 0.9231  0.1026                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


WASP.ABUN=structure(list(SITE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), 
    TIME = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), VEG = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), iCHNA = c(8L, 
    4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 17L, 4L, 17L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("SITE", "TIME", "VEG", 
"ABUNDANCE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: It is better now. However a few terms are not clear. pl. explain sampling period and WASPAV Site/Time

Comment: Sampling period = WASPAV$TIME; we sampled the wasps, trapped them, at the same locations twice. For Site/Time do you mean Error(Site/Time)? From what I'd seen online of other repeated ANOVAs this was the correct assignment of the error term for my data. Site is identifier of each trap location.

Comment: yes. Error(site/time). not yet clear about coding or scoring and is that an 'interaction term) frequently used in anova ?

Comment: I think when you do a RM anova you put the within-subject variable, which is TIME, along with the identifier of each subject, here SITE, as the error term. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: waspaov ,waspav ?  you appear to be working on some part correctly.

Comment: WASPAV was just a random name I made for the data frame. I will edit it to avoid confusion

Comment: How many locations and what is n = 10 and  n=4 n=6 ?

Comment: 10 locations per sampling period($TIME). n=4 and n=6 refers to the $VEG (between subject) grouping, so in each sampling period, 4 sites where situated in one vegetation/forest type, 6 in another vegetation/forest type

Comment: please elaborate  wasp aov equation  particularly abbreviations etc.

Comment: ABUNDANCE = Abundance of wasp group at each location;
TIME = Sampling period, 1 or 2 i.e. First and Second;
VEG = Vegetation/forest type;
SITE = Site/location number, 1 - 10;

Comment: how do you. measure /quantify abunndance and diversity

Comment: Abundance was just a count of the number of wasps at each site. Don't worry about diversity at this stage

Comment: Is it average of wasps  for  all samples. Iam getting confused ?

Comment: No it is not an average, it is the total number of wasps retrieved from the traps at each location.

Comment: do you want to prove with the  help of RM Anovathat vegetation type has effect on the number of wasps given a specific time and location ? hypothesis No. 1?

Comment: Yes, whilst at the same time seeing if wasp abundance differs, on the whole, between time/sampling periods

Comment: please  describe your code - WASP.Aov and how do you compute Abundance.

Comment: What is unclear? I believe I have explained everything properly

Comment: are you interested in  accuracy  or structure of the model or the interpretation of results for meeting goals of your study ?  state your  statistical hypotheses ?

Comment: i interested if I have applied the model accurately given I have a small sample size, esp. between veg types (between subject factor). My hypotheses are that there should be differences between the two veg types and the two time periods in wasp abundance

Comment: you are working on a number of locations and repeat samples, there is no statistcal problems, if measurements have been properly carried out. Model for TIMe needs a rethinking.  NOT SURE, error term should be different from the one implemented by you? what are the interprations you have arrived at.

Comment: do indicate some information regarding your qualification/ experience etc.

Comment: It may be useful to roll up some of the information added in comments into the main question with an edit (e.g. that "abundance" is a count of the wasps caught at each site); then I think it's clear enough. Thanks for your efforts @subhashc.davar!

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Scortchi, I have rolled up some of the info from the comments into the main question.  And, thank you for all your help @subhashc.davar!